# Why does message keep getting pulled even after ack'ing it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

```
(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub topics create Topic
Created topic [projects/project-id/topics/Topic].

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions create Sub --topic=Topic
Created subscription [projects/project-id/subscriptions/Sub].

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub topics publish Topic --message=A
messageIds:
- '1187813469495553'

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull Sub
Listed 0 items.

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull Sub
┌──────┬──────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ DATA │    MESSAGE_ID    │ ATTRIBUTES │ DELIVERY_ATTEMPT │ACK_ID          │
├──────┼──────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ A    │ 1187813469495553 │            │                  │ ack-ID-1       │
└──────┴──────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions ack Sub --ack-ids=ack-ID-1
Acked the messages with the following ackIds: [ack-ID-1]
{}

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull Sub
┌──────┬──────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ DATA │    MESSAGE_ID    │ ATTRIBUTES │ DELIVERY_ATTEMPT │  ACK_ID        │
├──────┼──────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ A    │ 1187813469495553 │            │                  │ ack-ID-2       │
└──────┴──────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘

(env) user@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull Sub
┌──────┬──────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ DATA │    MESSAGE_ID    │ ATTRIBUTES │ DELIVERY_ATTEMPT │  ACK_ID        │
├──────┼──────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ A    │ 1187813469495553 │            │                  │ ack-ID-3       │
└──────┴──────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Should't the queue be empty after ack'ing the only ever published message?

Comment: Might it be the case that you can only ack a message after pulling it and BEFORE its ack deadline has expired?  If there is validity in that notion, then you may be pulling a message and then performing a gcloud ack AFTER the previous pull has already timed out in its allowed ack duration.  How long is your subscription defined to hold open acks for?  Maybe run a gcloud describe on the subscription and see what it returns?

Comment: That is correct, Sir. Care to turn that into an answer and earn those sweet 10 points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one performs a pull on a subscription, the message is not considered retrieved until after it has been acknowledged (acked).  One can only acknowledge a message following a pull.  When one pulls a message from a subscription, a timer is started (inside Pub/Sub).  One *must* acknowledge the message within this timer interval.  If not, the message is considered un-acknowledged.

In our example here, when we perform a `gcloud` command to pull the message, if we don't perform the follow-on `gcloud` ack command *before* the interval has expired, then the ack request will have no effect.  We have the ability to perform a pull using an auto-ack which means that the pull will also immediately ack the message.  If we want to perform an explicit ack, we must perform that within the ack timeout interval.